# Hibernate does not create Java classes. What can I do?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, netbeans

I am using NetBeans 6.5.1 and Hibernate 3.2.5.

I stepped through [this tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html) by using a different, existing database (Oracle 10g XE). The creation of the config file works fine, as well as the creation of the HibernateUtil.java class. The tutorial then wants me to run the reverse engeneering wizard, but this wizard does not exist. Instead I was using the "Hibernate Mapping Files and POJOs from Database".

There I have selected the tables I want to map and enabled "JDK 5 Language Features", "Domain Code" and "Hibernate XML Mappings". After selecting the package and clicking finished the "hibernate.reveng.xml" file is created and that's all.

There are no Java classes and NetBeans does not prompt me a message why nothing is created. What is wrong? Am I missing something and what should I do next?

Add:
[This tutorial](http://www.tinkerbox.com.sg/articles/2008/09/13/getting-started-with-hibernate-3-and-netbeans-6-5-beta-part-1/) shows how it should work with 6.5 (yeah I know,... beta). The steps to perform are exactly the steps I did, but still no classes are created.

Comment: The tutorial says to use at least Netbeans 6.8 or higher. So I would just recommend to update your NetBeans and it will probably work fine.

Comment: That might work but thats not the solution I am looking for. I am creating an web application for a customer who uses for all theire applications 6.5.1, therefore 6.8+ is currently not an option. There must be a way to let the classes be generated in 6.5.1.

Comment: Just in case, there is [a link for NetBeans 6.5](http://netbeans.org/kb/65/web/hibernate-webapp.html)

Comment: Thanks but it does the same as the second tutorial. But good to know that there is an official Netbeans tutorial for this version. The problem stays: No classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make a Hibernate.cfg.xml? I suppose so, even though I didn't read the whole tutorial to find out.As from what you are describing you are using a plugin/tool to generate mappings.

Make sure that your hibernate.cfg.xml is configured right. Saves lifetime.
installing a logger would also help you point where it goes wrong. (commons-logging or log4j).

If you really want to use hibernate, use maven/ant and generate your mappings, and anything you want with HibernateTools (in maven that would be http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-hibernate3/hibernate3-maven-plugin/ ). It will in the end, save you a lot of time and trouble. I'm not sure what netbeans uses to generate these, but I tried it in 6.8 and the results were everything but perfect, compared to what maven gave me.

Comment: It seems that there has been a problem with the configuration file. Therefore I created a new project, configured it correctly and now it does work.

Comment: Configurations can be a pain in the ass, therefor I do prefer not to be IDE-bound.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem using NB 6.9.1. Having searched further, it appeared that there is a known bug in that version. [Bug ref 190740](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=190740)

However, not totally satisfied with ("its a bug" as an answer) I tried it in NB 6.8 and got the same problem. After manually creating the POJOs and the mapping files as per the section at the end of the tutorial entitled "Creating POJOs and Mapping Files Individually" I then proceeded with the remainder of the tutorial and hit an error when trying to test the HQL. This actually highlighted an error in the Hibernate Configuration file editor, that is used at the beginning of the tutorial:

In the section "Modifying the Hibernate Configuration File", the tutorial says to add a property in the Miscellaneous Properties node of the hibernate.cfg.xml. If you follow the instruction and type the property value in by hand as per the tutorial then all well and good, BUT if - like me - you are a little lazy ;-) and use the design tab of the Netbeans editor to edit this property, then instead of entering the value "org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory", you will doubtless choose the value "org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTransactionFactory" from the dropdown. It looks rather similar but in fact, No!, the editor has a spelling mistake: i.e it says "TransACTION" instead of "TransLATOR".

When I corrected this (i.e. set the property value to:

```
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">
    org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
```

and (importantly, I believe) REBUILT the project (I think I may also have restarted Netbeans for good measure although I'm sure that wasn't not strictly necessary), suddenly the "Hibernate Mapping Files and POJOs" wizard started strutting it stuff! This worked for me in both NB6.8 and NB6.9.1.  So now I can delete all the sakila.entity.* POJOs and also the resources/sakila.entity.* mapping files (and remove the `<mapping  />` entries it has created in the hibernate.cfg.xml file) et voila! the Mapping and POJO wizard will create them for me again no probs.

Hope that helps

Brian